# How can I make a square image fit inside of a rectangular div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that can be any size of a rectangle.  Then inside that div I have an image, that will always be a square.  How can I make that image be the largest possible size while still being able to fit the div.  Is there a way I can set the image's size to be equal to max(divWidth,divHeight) without using javascript?  Thanks for any responses.

Comment: ... `width:100%` `height:100%` ?? What have you tried

Comment: no, not without javascript. you need to find the largest side, and then scale the image in that dimension accordingly.

Comment: If you know beforehand which of your divs are longer than wide, then apply `height: 100%` else apply `width: 100%`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yd4VQ/ (if not, then you need js)

Answer (score 4):

Try the following CSS:

```
img.yourClass {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Zs8C8/

Comment: Haven't tested but this seems to be a pretty neat solution.

Comment: @Anar: I've added a link to a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
div {
    width: 50px; // or whatever
    height: 95px; // or whatever
    overflow: hidden; // prevents overlap if automatically adjusted height of img will exceed height of this parent div
}
img {
    width: 100%;// will always fit parent div, height wil adjust automatically
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="whatever">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `img` style `width: 100%` and/or `height: 100%`

```
<div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="..."></img>
</div>

<style>
.imgContainer{
    width: 200px; /*the size is up to you*/
    height: 200px; /*the size is up to you*/
}

.imgContainer>img{
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

If I set the `img` `width: 100%;`, the image height will be scaled automatically

Here is the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/uN2K4/